# Is there any possibility to integrate Control-M job execution (Automated) with UFT or any other automation tool?

Tags: automation, batch-processing, hp-uft, control-m, uft14

Our UFT Script performs some actions on a windows application and after that we need to execute Control-M Jobs, to verify the results. 
We are planning to handle all this actions from Automation Script itself. Is it possible?

Comment: Generally speaking, UFT can do anything an end user can, so the answer to this is very likely Yes.  Although you'd need to give significantly more detail to be able to get any help on doing so, such as including your code attempt at making this happen and detailing where you are having difficulties.  Have a read of [ask] and see if you can provide enough detail to make a proper question of this?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you can execute commands upon completion of UFT scripts you could use various Control-M utilities to perform whatever action you are after.

For example using `ctmorder` would allow you to force in Control-M jobs for execution or `ctmcontb` to create conditions in the Control-M environment.

You can find out more about available Control-M utilities and their purposes by looking at the Control-M Utilities Guide.